# Vue.js -Importing custom directive as ES6 Module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a rather specific question.

I'm using vue in my rails application through rails webpacker, to use vue components, I have to put a javascript pack tag in my layout and that references a javascript file that in turn renders the vue component, you can imagine that in total this approach has led me to make a lot of workarounds, but the one thing I still have left is a vue custom directive `click-outside` that I have had to add to each of my vue component generators, for example, here in `filter-products.js`

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import filterProducts from "../../views/filter-products";
var element = document.getElementById("filter-products");
const props = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute("props"));

Vue.directive('click-outside', {
    bind: function(el, binding, vNode) {
    //bind logic
    },

    unbind: function(el, binding) {
    //unbind logic
    }
});

if (element != null) {
  new Vue({
    render: (h) => h(filterProducts, { props }),
  }).$mount(element);
}
```

the custom directive code is actually big, so what I have in mind but am not sure how to do is one of two things:

- Have the bulk for that custom directive in an ES6 Module and import that here and just use it directly.
- Create a prototype for Vue that includes this custom directive and import it instead of importing `vue from "vue"`.

Is either of the approaches better? and how would I achieve them? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a folder named `directives` and for each directive create a file to make your code more organized and maintenable especially in team :

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const directiveName = {
    inserted: function(el, binding) {},
    update: function(el, binding) {},
};

export default directiveName;
Vue.directive('directiveName', directiveName);//optional
```

then import it in any component like :

```
import directiveName from 'path-to-directives-folder/directives/directiveName'
```

then use it as follows :

```
data(){
  ...
},
directives:{directiveName}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I'd like to use it in the part where I do new Vue() as in my question, is that possible?

Comment: Worked fine, just changed the usage to `Vue.directive("click-outside", clickOutside);`

Comment: where `clickOutside` is the imported file name

Comment: the directiveName is just an example, the directive could be imported anywhere in your vue app (main.js and the components